# How can I perform a SQL JOIN using Django ORM when the models are not related?

Tags: python, django, orm, left-join

I have two models that look like this:

(tableA)

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    student_id = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

(tableB)

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    student_id = models.TextField()
    report_card_file_id = models.TextField()
    # Other fields in ModelB
```

I created a sql query to join them that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    tableA.*,
    tableB.report_card_file_id
FROM
    tableA
    LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.student_id = tableB.student_id
    where tableB.report_card_file_id is not null;
```

But how can I transform this query into Django orm so that I will have a QuerySet with student_id, name, age, and report_card_file_id?

Here is some code I have, but I am not sure how to fill in the ?:

```
a = ModelA.objects.all()
a = a.annotate(?)
```

I also tried using .raw() but then I get a RawQuerySet instead of just a QuerySet.